# URL Encode/Decode issue with ServiceStack.net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, rest, servicestack

Through my testing, it seems that servicestack is automatically URL decoding any parameters sent through the query string of a GET request, but does not automatically decode params sent via a POST request.

Is there anyway that I can check the HTTP method and decode through my code for POST requests?

**EDIT**

My methods are derived from a class which implements the RestServiceBase class from Servicestack.net.

Is there any way to check the HTTP method from the current request via RestServiceBase?

Comment: have you tried HttpUtility.HtmlEncode

Comment: Yes but my services are derived from a base class which is unaware(as far as I know) of the HTTP method. If I use the Decode method on a GET request I will have effectively decoded the paramter twice which could cause issues.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion over the difference between POST and GET. POST submits a form without appending parameters to the URL, rather it will send it in the body of the request. GET is the method that appends the form fields to the URL.

Comment: Yes, but on the client side, the POST parameters are URL encoded as part of the request

Comment: I suggest examine using wireshark or some tool like this.  It probably puts your query params into body of request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the wire format? i.e. is it application/json or application/x-www-form-urlencoded ? because only application/x-www-form-urlencoded Content-Type's should be encoded.

Now if your POST'ing with a C# ServiceClient then we don't support POST'ing application/x-www-form-urlencoded and it's likely that JSON or XML, etc (depends on the ServiceClient) is being posted instead which doesn't require Url Encoding.

If you're POST'ing from jQuery then it should automatically be doing the url encoding for you.

Either way, can you post the HTTP Request payload so we can see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I use jQuery encoding in client side:

```
var sear = htmlEncode($("#Search").html());
.
.
.
function htmlEncode(value) {
    if (typeof (value) != "undefined") {
        return $('<div/>').text(value).html();
    }
    return "";
}

function htmlDecode(value) {
    if (typeof (value) != "undefined") {
        return $('<div/>').html(value).text();
    }
    return "";
}
```